# PowerBI live dashboard not updating in real time from Rest API

Tags: powerbi

I've got a small simple console app pushing data into a PowerBI dataset. The data is going in, but the dashboard does not appear to be updating in real time.

If I manually refresh the dashboard I can see the latest data, but it does not automatically update when I add rows to the table.

I've got a fiddler output of the request/response so I can see data is going across.

```
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/e6373821-c2ed-438a-967a-febe163dca75/tables/LiveCpu/rows HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Bearer xxxx
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: api.powerbi.com
Content-Length: 65
Expect: 100-continue

{"rows":[{"Timestamp":"2016-04-29T11:49:01","Value":31.8878784}]}
```

The response back is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
RequestId: 9daaabb9-e76d-4684-8ed3-1f6dc37889ab
Date: Fri, 29 Apr 2016 10:48:59 GMT

0
```

So all looks ok, but the live dashboard is not updating. I can even see messages in the web browser developer tools showing the request id has gone through, but no live updates.

Comment: Which types of tiles are you using on your dashboard?

Comment: I'm using a simple line chart showing value by timestamp. The axis is timestamp, the values are sum of value.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem was that I pinned an entire report to a dashboard rather than an individual report tile. Single report tiles do not appear to support automatic refresh.

Comment: Thanks Nick. That helped!

Comment: I know this is old, but your answer seems to contradict itself.